# Using TFS command line tf.exe how can I copy a repo to a folder location of my choice?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I have stared using TFVC for my MSVS 2015 C++ project. I am used to command line repos like git/svn, where I can simply do a checkout/clone, etc... and copy the files to any folder I like.

So, I have checked out my workspace to a mapped location (c:\myworkspace) via the MSVS2015 GUI. But now I want to to run my auto test script, which will copy the latest files from the repo to the current directory (e.g. c:\autorun). The auto test script builds and tests and generates results etc... But I **don't** want it to just over-write what I have in my workspace in case someone else has added a change.

I want it to go to a different folder of my choice.

In Git I would just navigate to the folder (cd c:\autorun) and then do `git clone <repo-path>`. But I can't see how this is possible with TFVC's workspaces.

So far I have started to modify my script that worked with git to get this:

```
' Clean any existing files:
rmdir /S /Q <projname>

' Checkout project
tf checkout <projname> /recursive

' Do other stuff (build test etc...)
```

But this only works in my c:\workspace - and I don't want to delete/overwrite my local changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new (temporary) workspace using

```
cd temp
md newfolder
tf vc workspace /new ...
tf vc workfold /map $/Project/Folder c:\temp\newfolder
cd newfolder
tf vc get . /recursive
tf workspace /delete
```

Or you can use the little utility written by Neno Loje, [TfsExport](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/03/14/download-files-from-tfs-version-control-and-set-the-file-last-access-timestamp-to-the-file-s-last-check-in-time/).

**Update From OP**

Assuming that I start in the folder that I want to extract my projects into. I used the following:

tf dir shows the repos I have:

```
D:\sandbox\tfs-test > tf dir
$/:
$tfsRepo1 
$tfsRepo2
$tfsRepo3
```

I just want the first two repos:

```
tf vc workspace /new /noprompt cit
tf vc get tfsRepo1 /recursive
tf vc get tfsRepo2 /recursive
```

Then to tidy up:

```
tf workspace /delete cit /noprompt
rmdir /S /Q tfsRepo1 
rmdir /S /Q tfsRepo2
```

Note the use of /noprompt in various places so that there is no user interaction required.

Comment: This is awesome! - well done :) I had to modify your script a little to get it to work without prompts appearing - I will add an edit to your post. Can you explain what the "." does in your get? - is that just to point to the current folder?

Comment: That's to make sure you're downloading the files into the just created workspace in the current workspace.